# Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. But Model is provided in the return View

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I get this error and I know it has been asked a lot before. But I believe that my case is different as I have provided a model in my return View, I have tried lots of different solutions that I found online such as replacing @model IEnumerable with @model List or trying partial views but still nothing. So the error appears here:  @foreach (var singlecause in Model) {

**here is the file: _PoductList**

```
 @model IEnumerable<ProjectActionMVC.Models.SingleCause>
  @using ProjectActionMVC.Infrastructure     

  @foreach (var singlecause in Model) { 

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail"><a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Store", 
   new {id = singlecause.SingleCauseId })">
  @if (singlecause.IsHot)
  {
<div class="HotFlag"></div>
  }
  <a href="@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Cart", new { id = 
      singlecause.SingleCauseId })">
<div class="HeartLikeSmall"></div>
  </a>
  <img src="@Url.CauseCoverPath(singlecause.CoverFileName)" />
  </a>
                <div class="caption explore">
                    <h3>@singlecause.SingleCauseTitle</h3>
                    <p>@singlecause.Description</p>

                    <div class="progress">
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="@String.Format("{0:0.#}", singlecause.Votes)" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: @String.Format("{0:0.#}", singlecause.Votes)%;">
                            @String.Format("{0:0.#}", 
              singlecause.Votes)%
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  }
```

**Store controller**

```
  Store controller`using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
  using System.Web.Mvc;
 using ProjectActionMVC.ViewModels;
using ProjectActionMVC.DAL;
 namespace ProjectActionMVC.Controllers
 {
  public class StoreController : Controller
  {

  StoreContext db = new StoreContext();

// GET: Store
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var singlecause = db.SingleCauses.Find(id);

    return View(singlecause);
}

  public ActionResult List(string categoryname, string searchQuery = null)
{
    var category = db.Categories.Include("SingleCause").Where(c => 
  c.Name.ToUpper() == categoryname.ToUpper()).SingleOrDefault();
    if (category == null)
    {
        //throw a meaningful exception or give some useful feedback to the 
       user!
        return View();
    }
     var singlecauses = category.SingleCause.Where(s => (searchQuery == null 
||

   s.SingleCauseTitle.ToLower().Contains(searchQuery.ToLower()) ||

   s.CreatorsName.ToLower().Contains(searchQuery.ToLower())) &&
                                            !s.IsHidden);

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView("_ProductList", singlecauses);
    }

    return View(singlecauses);
}

public ActionResult SingleCauseSuggestions(string term)
{
    var singlecauses = this.db.SingleCauses.Where(s => !s.IsHidden && s.SingleCauseTitle.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower()))
        .Take(5).Select(s => new { label = s.SingleCauseTitle });

    return Json(singlecauses, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult CategoriesMenu()
{
    var categories = db.Categories.ToList();
    return PartialView("_CategoriesMenu", categories);
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (this.db != null)
    {
        this.db.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}   
 }         
  }`
```

What I am trying to do is to display a list of causes in Product list and singlecause in Model will generate page with singlecause details

**List Page**

```
 @{
   ViewBag.Title = "List";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_StoreLayout.cshtml";
}

<div id="products" class="page-section">

    @Html.Action("CategoriesMenu")

    <div class="page-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">

                    <form id="search-form" method="get" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-target="#productlist-section">
                        <input id="search-filter" type="search" name="searchQuery" data-autocomplete-source="@Url.Action("SingleCauseSuggestions")" placeholder="Search..." />
                        <input type="submit" value="" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h1 class="page-section-title">Explore</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">

                            @Html.Partial("_ProductList")

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>




                @section ScriptsBottom {

                    @System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
                    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

                    <script>
                        $(function () {

                            var ajaxSubmit = function () {

                                var $form = $(this);

                                var settings = {
                                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                                    url: $(this).attr("action"),
                                    type: $(this).attr("method")
                                };

                                $.ajax(settings).done(function (result) {
                                    var $targetElement = $($form.data("ajax-target"));
                                    var $newContent = $(result);
                                    $($targetElement).replaceWith($newContent);
                                    $newContent.effect("slide");
                                });

                                return false;
                            };


                            var setupAutoComplete = function () {
                                var $input = $(this);

                                var options = {
                                    source: $input.attr("data-autocomplete-source"),
                                    select: function (event, ui) {
                                        $input = $(this);
                                        $input.val(ui.item.label);
                                        var $form = $input.parents("form:first");
                                        $form.submit();
                                    }
                                };

                                $input.autocomplete(options);
                            };

                            $("#search-form").submit(ajaxSubmit);
                            $("#search-filter").each(setupAutoComplete);

                        });

                    </script>
                }
```

**here is details page**

```
 @model ProjectActionMVC.Models.SingleCause
         @using ProjectActionMVC.Infrastructure
      @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_StoreLayout.cshtml";
}

<div id="home">


    <div id="start" class="page-section">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="page-section-title">@Model.SingleCauseTitle</h1>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">


                    <img class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image" width="100%" src="@Url.CauseCoverPath(Model.CoverFileName)">


                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                    <div class="media-body">


                        <div class="progress">
                            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="@String.Format("{0:0.#}", Model.Votes)" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: @String.Format("{0:0.#}", Model.Votes)%;">
                                @String.Format("{0:0.#}", Model.Votes)%
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <ul class="list-inline">
                            <li><h3><strong>Created by:</strong></h3><dl><dd>@Model.CreatorsName</dd></dl></li>
                            <br />
                            <li><h3><strong>Date added:</strong></h3><dl><dd>@String.Format("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", Model.DateAdded)</dd></dl></li>
                            <br />
                            <li><h3><strong>@String.Format("{0:0.#}", Model.Votes)%</strong></h3><dl><dd>backed</dd></dl></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>

                    <a class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" href="@Url.Action("AddToCart", "Cart", new { id = Model.SingleCauseId })" role="button">
                        Sign up for this Cause
                    </a>
                        <br />

                        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Remind Me</button>
                            </div>

                            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> Share <span class="caret"></button><ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=145634995501895&display=popup&href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fexplorer">Facebook</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">E-mail</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

</div>
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div id="about" class="page-section border-top">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- .container-fluid -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                <h1 class="page-section-title">About this Project</h1>




                <h2><p class="lead">@Model.Description</p></h2>


                <h3>Section 1.10.32 of &quot;de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum&quot;, written by Cicero in 45 BC</h3>
                <p>&quot;Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?&quot;</p>

                <img src="../Content/img/22.jpg" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail"><br /><br />

                <h3>1914 translation by H. Rackham</h3>
                <p>&quot;But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?&quot;</p><br />



                <img src="../Content/img/44.jpg" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail"><br /><br />

                <h4>Section 1.10.33 of &quot;de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum&quot;, written by Cicero in 45 BC</h4>
                <p>&quot;At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.&quot;</p>

                <h3>1914 translation by H. Rackham</h3>
                <p>&quot;On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment, so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains.&quot;</p>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4 hidden-xs">
                <h3 class="page-section-title">Support This Cause</h3>
                <h4><p>Support this Cause only or simply <a href="login.html">Login</a> or <a href="login.html"> Register</a> to support other causes too!</p></h4><br />
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputName">First Name</label>
                        <input type="name" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName" placeholder="First Name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputSurname">Surname</label>
                        <input type="surname" class="form-control" id="exampleInputSurname" placeholder="Surname">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1">E-mail</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 hidden-xs">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form><hr>
                <br />
                <h3 class="page-section-title">Supported by:</h3>
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left media-middle">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../Content/users/f1.jpg" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">Alex Johnson</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left media-middle">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../Content/users/m1.jpg" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">Tom Smith</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left media-middle">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="media-object img-circle" src="../Content/users/f2.jpg" alt="...">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h4 class="media-heading">Kate Cabot</h4>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here are the error details:

```
  An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in 
    App_Web_gnswtc0l.dll but was not handled in user code
     System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=App_Web_gnswtc0l
  StackTrace:
       at ASP._Page_Views_Store__ProductList_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\Jolievin\Source\Repos\ProjectAction\ProjectActionMVC\ProjectActionMVC\Views\Store\_ProductList.cshtml:line 8
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
       at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
       at Castle.Proxies.Invocations.IView_Render.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
       at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
       at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.CastleInvocationToAlternateMethodContextAdapter.Proceed()
       at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.ExecutionTimer.Time(Action action)
       at Glimpse.Core.Extensions.AlternateMethodContextExtensions.TryProceedWithTimer(IAlternateMethodContext context, TimerResult& timerResult)
       at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateMethod.NewImplementation(IAlternateMethodContext context)
       at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateTypeToCastleInterceptorAdapter.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
       at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
       at Castle.Proxies.IViewProxy.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName)
       at ASP._Page_Views_Store_List_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Users\Jolievin\Source\Repos\ProjectAction\ProjectActionMVC\ProjectActionMVC\Views\Store\List.cshtml:line 30
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
       at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
       at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
       at Castle.Proxies.Invocations.IView_Render.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
       at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
       at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.CastleInvocationToAlternateMethodContextAdapter.Proceed()
       at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.ExecutionTimer.Time(Action action)
       at Glimpse.Core.Extensions.AlternateMethodContextExtensions.TryProceedWithTimer(IAlternateMethodContext context, TimerResult& timerResult)
       at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateMethod.NewImplementation(IAlternateMethodContext context)
       at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateTypeToCastleInterceptorAdapter.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
       at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
       at Castle.Proxies.IViewProxy.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at Castle.Proxies.AsyncControllerActionInvokerProxy.InvokeActionResult_callback(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at Castle.Proxies.Invocations.ControllerActionInvoker_InvokeActionResult.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
       at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
       at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.CastleInvocationToAlternateMethodContextAdapter.Proceed()
       at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.ExecutionTimer.Time(Action action)
       at Glimpse.Core.Extensions.AlternateMethodContextExtensions.TryProceedWithTimer(IAlternateMethodContext context, TimerResult& timerResult)
       at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateMethod.NewImplementation(IAlternateMethodContext context)
       at Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.AlternateTypeToCastleInterceptorAdapter.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
       at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
       at Castle.Proxies.AsyncControllerActionInvokerProxy.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at 

 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 
   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, 
   ControllerContext 
    controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at 


 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`
   1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, 
   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: `@Html.Partial("_ProductList")` - You're not passing any instance of a model to the view here.  Is this the one that's producing the error?

Comment: Yes, that is the one. But I don't quite understand what you mean by:

 passing any instance of a model to the view here

how can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

```
@Html.Partial("_ProductList")
```

The model is `null` because you're not supplying a model in the above line of code where you invoke the partial view.  In the above line of code you'd include another parameter for some model instance.  For example:

```
@Html.Partial("_ProductList", someModel)
```

Or if you don't have one, provide a non-null default:

```
@Html.Partial("_ProductList", new List<ProjectActionMVC.Models.SingleCause>())
```

Basically the structure you have is that your parent view (list page) is internally invoking and rendering your child view (product list).  So that parent view has to provide to the child view whatever it needs.  (Thus, in turn, the controller will have needed to provide to the parent view whatever *it* needs in order to do that.)

You appear to be passing a collection of your model to the view:

```
return View(singlecauses);
```

But the list page view itself needs to know about that model:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectActionMVC.Models.SingleCause>
```

And then in turn pass it along to the product list view:

```
@Html.Partial("_ProductList", Model)
```

Comment: This is great, now I don't have that error anymore, however the _ProductList is not working now completely. The list page does not display products anymore, so it looks like  @foreach (var singlecause in Model) is still not working properly.

Comment: @Jolievin: Well, there's *a lot* of code in your question.  It's certainly possible there's some other logical error somewhere.  You're going to have to do some debugging to narrow down where the problem is.  Perhaps the list simply contains no elements?